# Adding intro image fadeIn wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I would like to add an image that fades in and then fades out after a certain amount of time. I have tried to add the code below into index.php and it works but it throws everything off like alignments and spacings. Where would I put this so that it only loads when the homepage is first loaded?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<img style="display: none; z-index: 9999;" id="book" src="images/test.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="100%">

<script>    
    $( "#book" ).fadeIn ( 2500, function() {});
    $( "#book" ).fadeOut( 1000, function() {});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use document on ready, it will fire a function when the document is loaded:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<img style="display: none; z-index: 9999;" id="book" src="images/test.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="100%">

<script>    
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#book" ).fadeIn ( 2500, function() {});
    $( "#book" ).fadeOut( 1000, function() {});
  });
</script>
```

let me know if it works

Answer (score 1):

run your functions after everything ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 //your code
});
```

it may work.

and have a look at
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script